# Xtend generation with Maven creates wrong String concatenation

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xtext, xtend

When my maven script generates Java from Xtend files,  , it generates files with wrong string concatenation.

xtend:

```
def writeImports(f){
    ''' 
         import "test.file"
         «getImports()»
    '''
}
```

Generated Java

```
public CharSequence writeImports () {
    StringConcatenation _builder = new StringConcatenation();
    _builder.append("import "test.file"");
    _builder.newLine();
    _builder.append("�getImports()�");
    _builder.newLine();
    return _builder;
}
```

Eclipse with the same xtend version generates the correct and expected format, :

```
public CharSequence writeImports () {
       StringConcatenation _builder = new StringConcatenation();
      _builder.append("import "test.file"");
      _builder.newLine();
       String _getImports = this.getImports();         
      _builder.append(_getImports , "");
      _builder.newLine();
      return _builder;
}
```

(eclipse also creates an extra xtendbin file)

The maven script is basically the same as explained in the xtext tutorial, https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/350_continuous_integration.html

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>xtend-install-debug-info</goal>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                <goal>xtend-test-install-debug-info</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>xtend-gen</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

I tried some different xtend versions but it didnt help. Do i need to set some configuration for xtend? Where can i find the possible configuration settings? How do i get the correctly generated file with Maven? 
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: At a guess some sort of character encoding problem since it doesn't look like it recognized the '«' and '»' characters.

Comment: Was thinking the same but i didn't know how to set the character encoding, until now, and it seems to fix it: <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>xtend-gen</outputDirectory> <encoding>Windows-1252</encoding>
</configuration>